# how to import gorm db connection from another file or package

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm learning go and I've recently learned how to leverage gorm to connect to a database. I can't figure out how to import said connection. Only open and defer it's closing in the scope of the `func main()`

What I have currently:

```
func main(){
  db, _ := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=someUser dbname=someDB password=somePW sslmode=disable")
  defer db.Close()
}
```

This works fine and I can create tables and do CRUD ... but all in the main function.

Is there anyway I can do something like this(it didn't work) and use it in main:

```
func db(){
  db, _ := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=someUser dbname=someDB password=somePW sslmode=disable")
  defer db.Close()
  return db
}
```

Or define some kind of package that will also allow me to do this.

I know that defer will basically just close the connect once db returns, but hopefully you guys get what I'm going for.

Comment: `dataBase := db()` something like this? compiler did not like that

Comment: yeah that makes sense, so an instance of the db can't be imported into other files?

Comment: what would the type of the argument be in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a package to hold the [database value](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB):

```
package db

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

var DB *gorm.DB

func Open() error {
   var err error
   DB, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=someUser dbname=someDB password=somePW sslmode=disable")
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }
}

func Close() error {
  return DB.Close()
}
```

In `main()`, open the database and close it on return:

```
package main

import (
    "import/path/of/package/db"
)

func main() {
    if err := db.Open(); err != nil {
       // handle error
    }
    defer db.Close()
    ... do stuff
}
```

Any package can import the db package and access the database as `db.DB`.

```
package foo 

import (
    "import/path/of/package/db"
)

func doSomethignWithDB() {
   db.DB.Query("hello")
}
```

Another approach is to use what you currently have working. Open the database in main and pass it to the functions that need it:

```
import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

func main(){
  db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=someUser dbname=someDB password=somePW sslmode=disable")
  if err != nil {
     // handle err
  }
  defer db.Close()
  doSomethingWithDB(db)
}

func doSomethingWithDB(db *gorm.DB) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Both make sense, unfortunately I need the data type for `.Open()`'s return. I looked through the docs and couldn't find anything regarding it. Looking at the source `func Open(dialect string, args ...interface{}) (db *DB, err error)` seems `*DB` is the type?

Comment: however, that by itself isn't working because the type isn't defined locally

Comment: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm you are an amazing person and I wish nothing but fortuitous things for you

Comment: as a go developer, which is the better option?