# GORM DB Connection on other package

Tags: go

I start learning Go, reading about pointers, and want to split my database connection , and handler function for API. Already tried myself, by following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751788/how-to-import-gorm-db-connection-from-another-file-or-package) , but when i trying to read data, i am having this error

**[2018-06-26 21:59:45]  sql: database is closed**
this is my source code.

db.go

```
package db

import (
"fmt"

"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
"github.com/joho/godotenv"

"os"
)

var Db *gorm.DB

func Open() error {

  var err error
  _ = godotenv.Load(".env")

  dbType := os.Getenv("DB_TYPE")
  dbConnString := os.Getenv("DB_CONN_STRING")

  Db, err = gorm.Open(dbType, dbConnString)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  Db.LogMode(true)
  defer Db.Close()

  return err
}

func Close() error {
    return Db.Close()
}
```

person.go

```
package model

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "fmt"
    "namastra/gin/result"
    "namastra/gin/db"
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:”firstname”`
    LastName  string `json:”lastname”`
}

/*var db *gorm.DB
var err error*/

func GetPeople(c *gin.Context) {

    var people []result.Person
    if err := db.Db.Select("ID,first_name,last_name").Find(&people).Error; err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, people)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "namastra/gin/handler"
    "namastra/gin/model"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/adam-hanna/jwt-auth/jwt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"

    "namastra/gin/db"
)

func main() {
if err := db.Open(); err != nil {
    // handle error
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()

router := gin.Default()
router.Use(gin.Recovery())
private := router.Group("/auth")

....(ommited)

router.GET("/", gin.WrapH(regularHandler))
router.GET("/people/", model.GetPeople)
router.Run("127.0.0.1:3000")
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, any kind of help is appreciated.

thank you.

edit1: **case closed.**

solution is by removing

```
defer Db.Close()
```

from db.go.

edi2: **update some knowledge i learn by working in go project**

Comment: You are closing Db connection within Open function itself, how can it is available for further operation? `defer Db.Close()`

Comment: [Without major changes Open function](https://play.golang.org/p/IgA1hRc_2xt)

Comment: ah, i see. got it. thanks @jittakal .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As start learning GO, usually we put everything on single main.go file, and we think to split the code to multiple files.

That is the time Dependency **Injection comes** to play.

we can create something like this **Env** to store the handler.

```
type Env struct {
    db *sql.DB
    logger *log.Logger
    templates *template.Template
}
```

and create something like this in **models/db.go**

```
package models

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func NewDB(dataSourceName string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

**main.go** files

```
package main

import (
    "namastra/gin/models"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Env struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func main() {
    db, err := models.NewDB("postgres://user:pass@localhost/bookstore")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    env := &Env{db: db}

    http.HandleFunc("/peoples", env.peoplesIndex)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func (env *Env) peoplesIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   # ...
}
```

and in **models/people.go**

```
package models

import "database/sql"

type Book struct {
    Isbn   string
    Title  string
    Author string
    Price  float32
}

func AllPeoples(db *sql.DB) ([]*People, error) {
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM peoples")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    # ... ommited for simplicity
}
```

you can read the full code & explanation in [Alex Edwards post](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access)